# How can I determine who is calling my Python script?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, subprocess, parent

I am writing a Python script, and I'd like its behaviour to depend on who's calling that script:

- if it is called from within a batchfile, I want the Python script to write its output to a logfile.
- if it is called manually from a command prompt, I want the Python script to write its output on screen.

My batchfile looks as follows:

```
  python py_script.py
```

Is there any way to get this done? I had a look at `os.environ.has_key()` but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Why not just pipe the output to a log when calling the script in the batch file?

Comment: Or make an explicit parameter to set the output/logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is (as tobias_k remarks in the comments) merely to pipe to a log file when called from a script

```
REM This is your batch file
python py_script.py >> your_log_file.txt
```

Bruno's suggestion in the other answer to pull a flag from `sys.argv` is certainly valid, but you're going to end up doing a lot of duplicate code. Your codebase will then look like:

```
if LOGGING:
    with open(PATH_TO_LOGFILE, 'a') as logf:
        logf.write(some_txt)
else:
    print(some_txt)
```

anytime you have a print call. Alternatively you could do some INCREDIBLY ugly stuff like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if LOGGING:
        old_stdout = sys.sdout
        with open(PATH_TO_LOGFILE, 'a') as logf:
            sys.stdout = logf
            main()
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Honestly that's ugly and hackish (*and might not even work, I've never tried to reassign `sys.stdout`*). Just use shell redirection.

Comment: Now that I have seen your first proposal (based on Tobias_k's comment) I can't imagine what I was thinking when I asked that question. I have used the redirection to an output file and it is working great.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an argument to your script to tell him where to write... command line arguments are passed in `sys.argv`. There are a couple packages in the stdlib to deal with them but you might not have need for here that's the only option for your script.